# Computational complexity of weighted least squares

Tags: matrices, algorithms, computational-complexity, regression, linear-regression

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84495/computational-complexity-of-least-square-regression-operation), for $N$ observations and $C$ variables, the computational complexity of solving a linear regression problem $(X^\intercal X)^{-1}X^\intercal \mathbf y$ is $O(C^2N)$.

I am not good at analyzing complexity. If I were instead interested in *weighted* least squares, [which has solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares#Solution) $(X^\intercal W X)^{-1}X^\intercal W \mathbf y$, what would its computational complexity be?

**My attempt:**

I am just following the pattern from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3890773/complexity-of-matrix-multiplication-with-different-size#:%7E:text=If%20all%20three%20matrices%20were,under%20O(N4.75)), which seems to say that multiplying three matrices $M \times N, N \times P, P \times M$ is $O(MNP + M^2 P)$.

This gets me:

- Multiplying $X^\intercal W X$ is $O(CN^2 + C^2N)$
- Multiplying $X^\intercal W \mathbf y$ is $O(CN^2 + C^2N)$
- Computing the LU of $X^\intercal W X$ and using it to compute the product $(X^\intercal W X)^{-1}X^\intercal W \mathbf y$ is $O(C^3)$

Since we assume $N > C$, $O(CN^2 + C^2N)$ dominates $O(C^3)$, so the final answer is $O(CN^2 + C^2N)$.

Is this right?

Thanks.